# Store Image,Audio file into MySQL database with Java

Tags: java, mysql, image, jdbc, blob

I tried inserting an image (.jpg format) and audio file (.mp3 format) into MySQL db. I failed.

I have used `MEDIUMBLOB` as datatype for both the columns. Can anyone help.

```
 String INSERT_PICTURE = "INSERT INTO pictures(idpictures,photo) VALUES (?,?)";

 File file = new File("c:/new/1.jpg");
 fis = new FileInputStream(file);
 pst = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_PICTURE);
 pst.setInt(1, 67);
 pst.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int) file.length());
 pst.executeUpdate();
 conn.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have used MEDIUMBLOB as datatype for both the columns

for integer value you should make the column as integer.

your table should be:

```
CREATE TABLE image_table (             
       id int(5) NOT NULL,       
       image MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL                             
 );
```

if this is not help, please give more information about the problem (exception, compile-time..) or the result you got it.

Comment: MEDIUMBLOB is used for image and audio file. image_id or audio_id remains int. I have an error at FileInputStream, but I have mentioned FileNotFoundException. It did not work. I was unable to insert an image into the db. how would one insert an image or an audio file into database.